# Delay in loading console output

Tags: jenkins, console-output

My Jenkins job has around 25000 lines of console output

If I open the job and choose the option as 'Show in Plain Text', complete output is displayed within seconds.

But, if I choose the option console output, it takes several around 10 mins to display the complete output.

Can someone explain, why does it take so much time for Jenkins to display the content in console output.

Comment: This is a well-known bug in Jenkins (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-45150)
My recommendation is to use external log storage for that purpose.